# Using multiple ->setParameters in Symfony2 Query builder

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

I'm adding filters to my query builder but I'm getting an html 500 error when using both filters at the same time. One only one of them it works fine.

Simplified query code:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
              ->select('a.id')
              ->where('a.active = 1');

        if($year) {        
            $year = explode('-', $year);

            $query->andWhere('a.minYear >= :min AND a.year <= :maxYear')
                ->setParameters(array('minYear'=> $year[0], 'maxYear' => $year[1]));
        }

        if($hours) {
            $hours = explode('-', $hours);

            $query->andWhere('a.hours >= :minHours AND a.hours <= :maxHours')
            ->setParameters(array('minHours'=> $hours[0], 'maxHours' => $hours[1]));
        }

       return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Might be a copy/paste typo but you have :min instead of :minYear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have a wrong parameter `min` and `minYear`.

Secondly you should use `setParameter` method instead of `setParameters`. `setParameters` creates a new parameters collection and override existing one each time you call it. That is why:

```
    if($year) {        
        $year = explode('-', $year);

        $query->andWhere('a.minYear >= :minYear AND a.year <= :maxYear')
            ->setParameter('minYear', $year[0])
            ->setParameter('maxYear', $year[1]);
    }

    if($hours) {
        $hours = explode('-', $hours);

        $query->andWhere('a.hours >= :minHours AND a.hours <= :maxHours')
            ->setParameter('minHours', $hours[0])
            ->setParameter('maxHours', $hours[1]);
    }
```